# sql group by monthly sum and sum year by month

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

RDBMS - Latest Oracle

I'm out of my element here. I need to organize account transaction information by account and by month, and also use another column to show summed transactions for year to date. Here is a depiction of what I'm trying to get

```
ACCT_ID | ACCT_MM  | FISCAL_YYYY | FISCAL_MM_AMT | YTD_AMT
------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |    11    |     2018    |      25       |   100
    1   |    12    |     2018    |      50       |   150
    1   |    01    |     2019    |      20       |   20
```

I know you can get FISCAL_MM_AMT with a group by ACCT_MM, FISCAL_YYYY
this is all I have figured out so far.

```sql
SELECT ACCT_ID,ACCT_MM,FISCAL_YYYY,SUM(NVL(ACCT_TRNSCTN_AMT,0))
FROM TBL_ACCT_DETAIL
GROUP BY ACCT_ID,ACCT_MM,FISCAL_YYYY
```

Now how to combine this with the additional column YTD_AMT to that adds up all totals for that year up to the current month is what has me baffled. sql noob ftw.

Comment: Tricky, that. Which rdbms? MySql, sql server, oracle, ... ?

Comment: Also, how much data and how critical is the performance?

Comment: oracle  - alot of data on some environments but we are creating a static flat table - so for now don't worry about performance, this is rarely run to refresh table data.

Comment: Then you could fetch that data with a simple subquery, I think.

Comment: thanks bud! you're correct - not all sure about the partition function but the below answer seemed to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try analytical function `SUM` as following:

```
SELECT T.*,
SUM(FISCAL_MM_AMT) 
OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_ID, FISCAL_YYYY
ORDER BY ACCT_MM) AS YTD_AMT
FROM
(SELECT ACCT_ID,ACCT_MM,FISCAL_YYYY,SUM(NVL(ACCT_TRNSCTN_AMT,0)) AS FISCAL_MM_AMT
FROM TBL_ACCT_DETAIL
GROUP BY ACCT_ID,ACCT_MM,FISCAL_YYYY);
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cumulative sum window function:

```
SELECT ACCT_ID, ACCT_MM, FISCAL_YYYY,
       COALESCE(SUM(ACCT_TRNSCTN_AMT), 0),
       SUM(SUM(ACCT_TRNSCTN_AMT)) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_ID, FISCAL_YYYY ORDER BY ACCT_MM) AS YTD
FROM TBL_ACCT_DETAIL
GROUP BY ACCT_ID, ACCT_MM, FISCAL_YYYY
```

Comment: _If_ he's not using an older MySQL which doesn't have window functions. Also, YTD needs to hold **the sum until the current month**, not the sum for the whole year.

Comment: @Vilx- . . . This calculates the cumulative sum for the year.  The OP also changed the tag to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have one additional column bringing the sum of the year with it, and a year-to-date column?

OLAP functions are a prerequisite. But every respectable RDBMS should offer those by now.

Then, I think (adding what I presume should be the input) ... you should go:

```
WITH
---- this is just the input so I have example data
input(     acct_id,acct_mm,fiscal_yyyy,fiscal_mm_amt) AS (
          SELECT 1,      1,       2018,            5 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,      3,       2018,            5
UNION ALL SELECT 1,      4,       2018,            5
UNION ALL SELECT 1,      5,       2018,           10
UNION ALL SELECT 1,      6,       2018,           10
UNION ALL SELECT 1,      7,       2018,           10
UNION ALL SELECT 1,      8,       2018,           10
UNION ALL SELECT 1,      9,       2018,           10
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     10,       2018,           10
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     11,       2018,           25
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     12,       2018,           50
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     01,       2019,           20
)
---- end of input -----
SELECT
  *
, SUM(fiscal_mm_amt) OVER(
    PARTITION BY acct_id,fiscal_yyyy
  ) AS fiscal_yy_amt
, SUM(fiscal_mm_amt) OVER(
    PARTITION BY acct_id,fiscal_yyyy 
    ORDER BY acct_mm
  ) AS ytd_amt
FROM input;

-- out  acct_id | acct_mm | fiscal_yyyy | fiscal_mm_amt | fiscal_yy_amt | ytd_amt 
-- out ---------+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------
-- out        1 |       1 |        2018 |             5 |           150 |       5
-- out        1 |       3 |        2018 |             5 |           150 |      10
-- out        1 |       4 |        2018 |             5 |           150 |      15
-- out        1 |       5 |        2018 |            10 |           150 |      25
-- out        1 |       6 |        2018 |            10 |           150 |      35
-- out        1 |       7 |        2018 |            10 |           150 |      45
-- out        1 |       8 |        2018 |            10 |           150 |      55
-- out        1 |       9 |        2018 |            10 |           150 |      65
-- out        1 |      10 |        2018 |            10 |           150 |      75
-- out        1 |      11 |        2018 |            25 |           150 |     100
-- out        1 |      12 |        2018 |            50 |           150 |     150
-- out        1 |       1 |        2019 |            20 |            20 |      20
-- out (12 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (12 rows): 76.235 ms. All rows formatted: 76.288 ms
```